# Jinja2 render custom view

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

i'm developing a website with flask-python.I create a html file in a variable.Can i render this variable instead of writing render_template('index.html')?
Here's my code:

```
 replacedView = rc.replaceActions()
```

Now replacedView has a html file's code.My purpose is say to jinja2 render this.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my question.The answer was so easy.
At the final i have a variable which has html inside.So i returned it.So there was it!

```
return replacedView
```